# How to detect the end of the list element on scroll event?

Tags: reactjs, react-window

How to detect the end of the list element on scroll event? Lets say i have array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, i need to detect if the scroll was reached the end of the list and return then value(in this case the value is 10)? Here is my snippet code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-detect-last-element-on-scrolling-down-oo99p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onScroll event for parent div:

```
const onScroll = (event) => {
  var element = event.target;
  if (element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight)
  {
      console.log(dataArray[dataArray.length - 1]);
  }
}
```

See in playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-window-detect-last-element-on-scrolling-down-c4sv0?file=/src/index.js